# Stack implementation crashes while trying to print en element of the stack

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, stack

I'm trying to implement a dynamic stack using an array. The user enters the number of the letters of the word he wants to put in the stack. If the stack is empty then a block is created to hold the information that the user passes to the stack. If not then the stack is reallocated so it can hold one more block of information(word). Then the user enters the word that he wants to be put in the stack(At the part that the index of the stack is printed). The program seems to crash after the second word is done entering the stack.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct stackElement {
    int stringLength;
    char *name;
} StackElement;
int Push(StackElement **stack,int *index);

int main()
{
    StackElement *stack = NULL;
    int index = -1;
    Push(&stack,&index);
    printf("The index is : %d\n", index);
    printf("The top word of the stack is %s\n", stack[index].name);
    Push(&stack,&index);
    printf("The index is : %d\n", index);//Crashes after this command is executed 
    printf("The second word of the stack is %s\n", stack[index].name);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int Push(StackElement **stack,int *index)
{
    if (*stack == NULL) {
        printf("The stack is empty\n");
        *index = *index + 1 ;
        *stack = malloc(sizeof(StackElement));
    } else {
        printf("The stack is not empty\n");
        *index = *index + 1 ;
        //Adding enough space for one more element in the stack
        *stack = realloc(*stack,sizeof(StackElement)*(*index+1));
    }
    printf("Enter the length of the word you want in the stack\n");
    scanf("%d", &(*stack[*index]).stringLength );
    (*stack[*index]).name = malloc(sizeof(char)*(*stack[*index]).stringLength );
    printf("Enter the word in the stack\n");
    scanf("%s", (*stack[*index]).name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not the error source, but you should really free your malloc´d space sometimes. Maybe someone will search the problem *then*. Side note: That´s not only a stack, with this index stuff and all...

Comment: I know that i need to free the occupied space at some point but I don't think it causes any conflicts at the current state of the program. I don't get what you are saying about the index but I will use it as the "Top" indicator that a stack has.

Comment: Sorry for my edit, but those extra blank lines stopped your code from fitting into the box. Which is bad for reading.

Comment: It's ok. Thanks for the correction my friend.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not easy to read because of so many pointers, but as far as I understand, you're misusing `realloc()`.

When stack is allocated for the first time, you use `*stack = malloc(sizeof(StackElement))` which works well.

When you re-allocate the stack (`realloc(*stack,sizeof(StackElement)*(*index))`) you pass as size the dimension of the struct multiplied by the variable `index`; at this time of the program index is equal to 1, so you're allocating exactly the same memory size as before (`sizeof(StackElement)`) and then accessing memory with an index greater than 0, you get the segmentation fault.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. The thing is the problem persists even if I change it to *index + 1 in the reallocation.

Comment: The only thing that comes in my mind is: do you really need all those pointers? Debugging is much more difficult and I'm pretty sure it screws up because of them!

Comment: Yeah I'm afraid that the usage of pointers is inevitable in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very nice but at least it works! You should remove your allocation from your function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct stackElement
{
    int stringLength;
    char *name;

} StackElement;

int Push(StackElement **stack,int *index);



int main()
{
    StackElement *stack = NULL;
    int index = -1;

        if(stack == NULL)
    {
        printf("The stack is empty\n");
        index = index + 1 ;
        stack = (StackElement*)malloc(sizeof(StackElement));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The stack is not empty\n");
        index = index + 1 ;
        stack = realloc(stack,sizeof(StackElement)*(index+1));//Adding enough space for one more element in the stack
    }

    Push(stack,&index);

    printf("The index is : %d\n", index);

    printf("The top word of the stack is %s\n", stack[index].name);

            if(stack == NULL)
    {
        printf("The stack is empty\n");
        index = index + 1 ;
        stack = (StackElement*)malloc(sizeof(StackElement));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The stack is not empty\n");
        index = index + 1 ;
        stack = realloc(stack,sizeof(StackElement)*(index+1));//Adding enough space for one more element in the stack
    }


    Push(stack,&index);

    printf("The index is : %d\n", index);//Crashes after this command is executed 

    printf("The second word of the stack is %s\n", stack[index].name);

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}



int Push(StackElement *stack,int *index)
{



    printf("Enter the length of the word you want in the stack\n");

    scanf("%d", &(stack[*index]).stringLength );

    (stack[*index]).name = malloc(sizeof(char)*(stack[*index]).stringLength );

    printf("Enter the word in the stack\n");

    scanf("%s", (stack[*index]).name);




    return 0;

}
```